Unable to install Parquet in Python 3.9.18 Virtual Environment on a Linux System due to setuptools dependency issue
I am trying to install Parquet-python into a Python 3.9.18 Virtual Environment on a generic Linux VM. Linux version is 5.14.0-427.20.1.el9_4.x86_64.
The command I used was
pip install parquet --proxy <myProxyDetails>
Which eventually fails with the error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: none)
Full Error text:
pip install --proxy http://<myproxydetails> parquet 
Collecting parquet
  Using cached parquet-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
Collecting thriftpy2 (from parquet)
  Using cached thriftpy2-0.5.1.tar.gz (781 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbd97a2af10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/setuptools/

... 3 repeated lines removed ...

      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbd979d0850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/setuptools/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I expected that Parquet should just down download and install without problems, as I have installed several packages already using the same proxy.
Assuming that the install of the thriftpy2 dependency was causing the problem, I tried to install it by itself:
pip install --proxy <proxy> thriftpy2
and got exactly the same problem.
The latest version 70.1.1 of setuptools is definitely installed in this environment (from pip show setuptools), but the install of thriftpy2 seems to be ignoring it, or it is ignoring the proxy.
Based on research, I tried the --no-dependencies argument, same result.
I also tried specifying setuptools==70.1.1 in a constraints.txt file, referenced using the -c argument. Same result.

You could try to update to Python 3.10 and create a new virtual environment. I create a new environment with Python 3.9 and can't install parquet. But with the environment in Python 3.10, I can install.
